# Can't use value on the outside from inside a function with PHP

Tags: php, function, scope, global

I have a function in `location.php` with this code:

```
    $isp = $ipInfo["isp"];
    $country = $ipInfo["country"];
    $state = $ipInfo["state"];
    $town = $ipInfo["town"];

    echo  "ISP: " . $isp . "<br>\n";
    echo  "Country: " . $country . "<br>\n";
    echo  "State: " . $state . "<br>\n";
    echo  "Town: " . $town . "<br>\n";
```

I have a file named `test.php`. If I use this code:

```
<?php
include('location');
    echo  "ISP: " . $isp . "<br>\n";
    echo  "Country: " . $country . "<br>\n";
    echo  "State: " . $state . "<br>\n";
    echo  "Town: " . $town . "<br>\n";
?>
```

inside `test.php` I get the following output:

```
ISP: dslb-094-219-040-096.pools.arcor-ip.net
Country: DE - Germany
State: Saarland
Town: Schiffweiler
ISP: 
Country: 
State: 
Town:
```

The second ISP, country, state and town are in `test.php` and do not show anything and the first ones are inside `location.php`. The whole problem is, I can't use a variable created inside the function on the outside or in another php file. How can I use a variable on the outside? 
It has to do with global and scope?

Sorry if I am confusing, but it's almost 3:30 am and I am getting nuts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the global keyword to do this

```
function my_func()
{
    global $isp,$country,$state,$town;
    //do stuff to variables
}
echo $isp.$country.$state.$town;
```

Something like that would work. Although a better option would probably be returning the variables in a return statement.

--edit--

Just made a working mockup

p1.php

```
<?php
function a()
{
    global $b,$c,$d;
    $b='hi';
    $c='bye';
    $d='what';
}
a();
?>
```

p2.php

```
<?php
include 'p1.php';
echo $b.$c.$d;
?>
```

There shouldn't really be any reason something like this wouldn't work for you.

Comment: I did this before posting. It did not work

Comment: @F4LLCON Edited my post with a tested and working script. Are you sure you executed the function before you tried to access variable?

Comment: Yes I've tested your code now and it works! I will go and cleanup my code

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to lift variables over `include` statements, it makes for messy code. `include` isn't like a function call.

Typically the kind of files you want to `include` are files that have just function or class definitions in them. And then you'll probably want to use `include_once`.

`include` can be useful for things like templates, where you might actually end up repeating the same file but for just PHP code: no.

The proper way would look like this:

```
// location.php
function printIPInfo($ipInfo) { // THIS is a function
    $isp = $ipInfo["isp"];
    $country = $ipInfo["country"];
    $state = $ipInfo["state"];
    $town = $ipInfo["town"];

    echo  "ISP: " . $isp . "<br>\n";
    echo  "Country: " . $country . "<br>\n";
    echo  "State: " . $state . "<br>\n";
    echo  "Town: " . $town . "<br>\n";
}

// test.php
include_once('location.php');
printIPInfo($ipInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure why you are having problems

I often have a "Dim.php" file to define constant strings and then include using:

```
include("location.php");
```

Using the .php extension may fix your problem?